# To print the modal content from the button outside the modal in another component in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, vuejs3, simplemodal

I have structture as follows

```
//main component
<button onClick="PrintModal()">Print</button>
<ModalComponent :active = active/>

//modal component
// All the modal headings and body
```

Now I want to print the modal contents from the button, the active is passed as a prop. And the modal is a form so all the values of the form are also passed as a prop while calling the modal component from the main component.

When I am using the window.print() it is printing the full screen not only the modal contents, but I want to print only the modal contents, I am not sure how to achieve this.

I have tried to do with the example in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278216/how-can-i-use-window-print-in-modal-vue?rq=2)
But it does not work.

Comment: What if you do the print inside the modal component you want to print?

Comment: Nope thats the functionality of my application I have to print from the outside

Comment: "I have tried to do with the example" - what did you try and what did not work?? It's more constructive to fix than write code from scratch

Comment: As I have separate components for the modal and where the print is, it is not working If I am placing the print button outside the modal it is printing everything.
@Etus Flask

Comment: It prints once we open the modal and it is in the DOM